# Is there a way to make * line in A more toward middle?

Tags: python

I made the program on my own and it looks like this:

```
X=eval(input('input the height of letter A: '))
B=1
A=0
V=X
print(' '*X,' *')
for i in range (X-3):
    A=A+B
    V=V-B
    print(' '*V,' *',' '*A, ' '*A,' *',sep='')
A=A+B
V=V-B
print(' '*(V-1),' *'*X)
for l in range (1):
    A = A + B
    V=V-B
    print(' '*V,'*',' '*(A-1),' '*(A-1),'*',)
```

It's quite raw I would say,but at least it gives me an A I need. Is there a way to tide it up and make a line more toward the middle?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Isn't the input number supposed to say how much starts are in the straight line? I would change `eval(input(...))` to `int(input(...))`

Comment: Also, since the code is working with no errors and giving you the desired output (almost...), I would say that this might be more suitable in [codereview.se]

Comment: You are right, I just copied from something I did earlier and  forgot to change eval, but it still gives me proper results on that part.

Comment: And maybe you are right, but I couldn't decide if this is considered a mistake or success, so I decided to write it here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the midpoint and store that value. Adjust the top\bottom ranges accordingly.

Try this code:

```
X=eval(input('Unesite visinu slova A: '))
B=1
A=0
V=X
midpt = (X-1)//2  # middle bar
print(' '*X,' *')
for i in range (midpt):
    A=A+B
    V=V-B
    print(' '*V,' *',' '*A, ' '*A,' *',sep='')
A=A+B
V=V-B
print(' '*(V-1),' *'*(A+2))
for l in range (X-midpt-2):
    A = A + B
    V=V-B
    print(' '*V,'*',' '*(A-1),' '*(A-1),'*',)
```

Comment: That's just what I needed.. Now it works perfectly,thank you.